# JPA PagingItemReader with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-batch

I have done a job that reads data from a db and writes it in a file. It works fine with an Oracle DB. However, when I use it with Postgres I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
Hint: Por ejemplo, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
Position: 15
Error Code: 0
```

The reader is defined as follows:

```
<bean id="myReader"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.Jpa PagingItemReader">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
<property name="queryString" value="select c from CountryEntity c" />
<property name="pageSize" value="1000"/>
</bean>
```

Does anybody know if this is a common issue related with Postgres? Do I need to use a specific configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your JPA provider to use the PostGreSQL dialect.

E.g. for Hibernate, you would use a setup (persistence.xml) like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="somename" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql:sample"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Patrick, thank you very much for your answer. I have tried with the the configuration you mentioned, but the problem has not been solved. I do not know if I am missing something... I have added in a new answer the configuration I have tried. Is it enough with that?